# Does Lower value in rows column of explain query means faster query

Tags: mysql, explain

I have a table, with about 10M entries, A select query is too slow, So I tried adding a composite index to the table, explain query shows lesser number of rows compared after adding the composite index. But on running the actual query, the test table in which the index is added sometimes takes, extra time than the table without index. I know that on running the same query multiple times, the time will be lesser as mysql optimises it. Is there a way to benchmark the actual performance improvements.

Explain result Without index

[image: Result1]

Explain result with index

[image: Result2]

Table desc and select query: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  "Probably".

Long answer:

Multiplying the the values in "Rows" column *sometimes* is a good metric of expected (relative) performance.  "Rows" is not visible in the second one; `Extra` sometimes have useful info.

If you want further discussion, please provide

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE
SELECT ...
```

Generally a composite index with the `=` columns first, followed by on "range" test is best.  More details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

In that link is a "better" way to benchmark queries:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

Comment: Thanks for the awesome blog link @Rick James, I was able to learn things, in the select query i have 4 cols in the where clause (=), I added all those columns to the index. According to the cookbook also this seems correct. Am I missing anything? Added the select query and table desc too. status is the new index i added.

Comment: @hades262000 - What is the definition of `index_packages_on_outward`?